# Iterate through NSArray and calculate difference

Tags: ios, loops

I have an NSArray with card objects with different values, let's say 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10. I want to determine whether a card is playable and I do this with the playable property of he card object, which obviously also has a value property. The rule is that when a card is playable (for this example only card 1 is playable) the card with a value that only differs 1 is also playable. So in the above example card number two is also playable, the rest is not. To be clear, the sorting may differ and is not always ascending or descending.

What I want is to iterate through the playerCards array and compare the 1 card with all other cards in the array and when the difference is 1 set the card's playable property to IsPlayable and then loop again until all playable cards are determined.

```
First loop attempt (card 1 is playable):
2-1 = 1 card value 2 is playable
3-1 = 2 card value 3 is not playable
5-1 = 4 card value 5 is not playable
8-1 = 7 card value 8 is not playable
10-1 = 9 card value 10 is not playable

Second loop attempt (card 2 is now also playable):
3-2 = 1 card value 3 is playable
5-2 = 3 card value 5 is not playable
8-2 = 6 card value 8 is not playable
10-2 = 8 card value 10 is not playable

Third loop attempt (card 3 is now also playable):
5-3 = 2 card value 5 is not playable
8-3 = 5 card value 8 is not playable
10-3 = 7 card value 10 is not playable

Stop loop.
```

I don't know exactly how to go about. This is what I got so far, but I am lost;

```
for(int x = 0; x < [playerCards count]; x++) 
{    
Card *playerCard = [playerCards objectAtIndex:x];
if(playerCard.playable == IsPlayable){
something like playerCard.value-otherplayerCard.value ???}
```

Could you guys help?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you just post the original text of your homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your `for` loop in a `while` loop, where the `while` loop checks if a change was made and the `for` loop makes changes (or not if everything is complete).

I'm going to assume that the `Card` classes have an `NSNumber` called `card`:

```
BOOL changed = YES;
NSMutableArray *playableCards = [NSMutableArray array];

while (changed) {

    changed = NO;

    for (Card *playerCard in playerCards) {
        NSNumber *card = playerCard.card;

        if (playerCard.playable == IsPlayable) {
            if (![playableCards containsObject:card]) {
                NSLog(@"Card %@ is already playable", playerCard.card);
                [playableCards addObject:card];
                changed = YES;
            }
        } else {
            NSNumber *cardUp = @(card.integerValue + 1);
            NSNumber *cardDown = @(card.integerValue - 1);

            if ([playableCards containsObject:cardUp] || [playableCards containsObject:cardDown]) {
                NSLog(@"Card %@ is being made playable", playerCard.card);
                changed = YES;
                playerCard.playable = IsPlayable;
                [playableCards addObject:card];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wain, it helped me a lot! The only problem I have now that the code keeps going on and on. How do I determine if all possible calculations have been done and then exit the loop?

Comment: You need to think about it and debug. I made it up on the spot and typed in a browser... You should get to a point where changed is NO, check what is making it YES.

Comment: Wain, thank you very much, I got. Removed the second "Changed = YES"  in your code example and it is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

There's a general programming pattern here that will be useful in other places. The pattern is that you start with some limited information and may add more information which in turn leads to more information; in this case "playable" cards are initially the ones that are marked as playable to start with, then those nearby to a playable card become playable, and so on. The pattern is

```
"start with initial data"
BOOL changed = YES;

while (changed)
{
    changed = NO;
    "try to find any new information"
    if ("any new information was found")
        changed = YES;
}
```